# Blender freezes for 30 seconds every time I click

Tags: performance, memory-management

I wrote one question about its limits. Blender was being cute hahaha. Still, after that scene, Blender is being a pain. I am dealing with the blue dial every click, it last for about 30 seconds, it takes 2 or 3 minutes to save the project and so much more. The first time it started acting like an idiot I could understand you know. Physics simulation, Hair Dynamics trying to freeze it failing succeeding, etc. However now it just seems to persist in anything I do. The scene I am working on is not very special it has no physics (as far as I know) going on am on frame zero, not really doing much (had much larger HP scenes working smoothly with cycles preview on). However, Blender is eating the hell out of my memory

[image]

The CPU is good though of course and the GPU is doing well.

64 percent is its default state if I click on anything it goes up a little bit higher and gives me the blue dial for up to 30 seconds. Sculpting just to smooth out a mesh is hell, click wait 30 seconds, click wait another 30 seconds, click and drag oy vey better hold on for a minute sometimes more.

I have 64gbs of Ram, ddr4, AMD Ryzen 9 3950x 16 cores, Windows 10, Nvidia Geforce 1660 Ti 6gbs, Blender 2.83.

So what is the issue? Is there a fix or do I just have to keep adding ram?
If the latter I can only go to 128gbs and I can promise I will hit that as well.

(not quite sure how to hand over scene files if needed. Also if you want it grotesque warning.)

Comment: Sometimes spending money for software can give you better performance than spending money for hardware.. Zbrush and sculpting is one example, Houdini and simulations is another. Tell us what you are doing and maybe we could figure out what you are either doing wrong or if you hit the ceiling of Blender's capabilities.

Comment: I think it is actually a bug. I think somehow Blender when you append things like an object it somehow opens the whole project in the background because after exiting and opening Blender it is working. Not sure what the hell is happening. I used to use Modo I just wanted to save on money and learned Blender. I use 3D coat for sculpting myself. Blender is a very annoying brat. 

I basically had a subpar HP (model with the highest poly count was 500k poly's) and I just had the above happening non-stop. I thought it was happening before the append now I dunno.

Comment: Please share some more information about the scene. 64 gigs of usage is quite a lot indeed, are the objects heavily subdivided? How many millions of vertices are you dealing with?

Comment: Faces 695,771, Vertices 1.2 million. 
Only one thing is Sub D and it is only to level 2 with a smooth modifier on it. Not a very heavy scene as you can see.

I dunno what is up with Blender but a few of my scenes that have been misbehaving the same way fixed themselves upon exiting and reentering. Not sure if a dynamic state got stuck after clearing it, or the append added the whole scene in the background even though I added only one minor object to it. I know one scene did not have any dynamics so that is why I assumed the append method is buggy. I appended from a much heavier scene.